Can I use Samsung's One UI Video Call Effects with my own video chat app?
The Samsung "Video Call Effects" feature in One UI lists "available apps" like Facebook Messenger, Google Meet, WhatsApp, and Zoom.
How do I go about integrating my own video chat app with Samsung's Video Call Effects, is there any way to do it? (throw something in the manifest, integrate with some special Samsung SDK, try and establish a partnership with Samsung, etc)?
